# Bootstrap ScrollSpy seems to be breaking Bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to implement ScrollSpy on a page which uses tabs.

This is my body tag:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="50">
```

This is my tabs HTML:

```
<div class="div-tabs tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <div class="padding16">
                   ...
            </div>
            <div class="button-bar">
                <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-user"></i>Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-time icon-white"></i>Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Button</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane " id="profile">
            <div class="padding16">
               ...
            </div>
            <div class="button-bar">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Button</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I remove the `data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="50"` from the  tag, my tabs work fine. With the scrollspy enabled, I get this error in Chrome dev tools:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Any idea what could be wrong? It looks like ScrollSpy is causing Bootstrap tabs to not find references to the HREF attribute.

I'm using Bootstrap 2.0.2

Comment: The code above is not production, it is just a template to be used through the rest of our system for building tabbed user interfaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I saw this error when I had links in the nav to anchors that did not yet exist in the markup. For instance, if a link in the navbar links to `#about`, but no element exists on the page with `id="about"`, you'll see this error.